# kendo UI Doesn't work Asp.net MVC 5.2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I install kendo ui asp.net mvc 2018.1.117 and 2016.

**1.** I add Style and JS Folder to my project and renamed both of them to "kendo" .

**2.** add reference to my project

**3.** I didn't config BundleConfig.cs because there was no BundleConfig.cs in my project

**4.** I add namespace to web.config

**5.** I add Styles and ... manually in my project like :

```css
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/kendo.common-material.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/kendo.mobile.all.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/kendo.material.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/jquery.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/angular.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/jszip.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.all.min.js")"></script>
```

I did all these steps and when I add kendo date Picker it doesn't work:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("datepicker"))
```

When I click inspect element it shows my css and js file but kendo ui doesn't work.

Dev tool screenshot:

[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Jitp.png)

Comment: I don't see a reference to [kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/what-you-need). Also, are you referencing the MVC5 version of Kendo.Mvc.dll? Have you considered letting Nuget set it up for you? See [here](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/getting-started/nuget-install).

Comment: I add "using Kendo.Mvc.UI" .  what do you mean for reference ?
I add reference from "aspnetmvc\Binaries\Mvc5" .

I dont download anything from nuget because ther wans nothing in nuget for downloading.

Comment: If you are licensed, the Nuget option should work if you setup the private feed with your credentials as described. That said, you don't need it. But yes, you need a reference to the binary. You also need the script kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js. Are you seeing console errors?

Comment: I dont use licensed version. I have been done all the steps of [link](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/getting-started/asp-net-mvc-5)  . but it doesn't work . I downloaded nuget.exe and ran that command but in Nuget Command when i type "Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Mvc5" it show this error : Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Mvc5 : The term 'Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Mvc5' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: Forget Nuget - it won't work in your case. Your code above is missing the script ~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js. Have you added that?

Comment: Ok. I added "~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js" and test it but no thing happen .

Comment: You getting script errors? Also check what got rendered.

Comment: No .when I run project this code : "@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("datepicker"))
"  , it just show a simple input like text box .